# How to show only top level error message of Oracle in my PHP Application

Tags: php, oracle, error-handling, oracle-call-interface

I have an application which connects to my Oracle Database through PHP OCI.

I am receiving the error from the database call like bellow

```
$r = oci_execute($stid);
   if (!$r) {

     $e = oci_error($stid); // For oci_execute errors pass the statement handle
     die($callback . '(' . json_encode(
     array_merge(
         array(

          'STATUS' => 'FALSE'
        ),
       array(

        'ERROR_MESSAGE' => $e['message']
      )
     )
   ) .
' )
');
```

My problem is, the error is always too long because it drills down to the source of the error like below

> "ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
>   ORA-06512: at "APPOWN.CLIENTINTERFACE", line 133 ORA-06512: at
>   "APPOWN.CLIENTORDER_API", line 3609 ORA-06512: at
>   "APPOWN.CLIENTORDER_API", line 447 ORA-06512: at
>   "APPOWN.CLIENTORDER_API", line 3184 ORA-06512: at line 26"

I only need the top level error message like below

> (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

Is there a way (except doing some text work on the response string) to get a simple error message?

Comment: I think you are not handling Exception in your block. post some oracle part which might help us to answer.

Comment: In PL/SQL procedure you can use system functions `SQLERRM` (text message) and `SQLCODE` (code of error). But I don't know how they can be accessed in PHP.